# SpringBoot MongoDB returns "Id must be assignable to Serializable! Object of class [null] must be an instance of interface java.io.Serializable"

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mongodb

I tried adding a new collection to my API/DB today, and when I try to POST or GET, I get this 500 error response:

```
{
  "cause": null,
  "message": "Id must be assignable to Serializable! Object of class [null] must be an instance of interface java.io.Serializable"
}
```

However the POST is actually successful, I can see the new data in the DB.

**Model**:

```
@Setter
@Getter
public class League {

    private String name;
    private String shortName;
    private List<Team> teams;
}
```

**Repository**:

```
@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "leagues", path = "leagues", excerptProjection = LeagueProjection.class)
public interface LeagueRepository extends MongoRepository<League, String> {

}
```

**Projection**:

```
@Projection(name="LeagueProjection", types={League.class})
public interface LeagueProjection {

    String getName();
    String getShortName();
}
```

I am not doing anything special. I have multiple other collections that work fine.

I am using spring-boot 1.5.1.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Adding the field:

```
@Id private String id;
```

to my model seems to have resolved the issue.